# tar using short form option versus old style

Tags: command-line, tar

In the GNU manual for `tar`, there is the following example to show that the order of the options is important:

```
tar -cfv collection.tar blues folk jazz
```

In this case, because `v` is placed after `f`, then the tar archive will be named "v", and `tar` will try to add `collection.tar` to the archive if it exists in the current directory. But if I omit the `-` from the beginning, then the command works as we would want it to, despite `v` being placed after `f`. Why?

Comment: Reviewers: [Questions like this are on-topic.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15141) It [would still be on-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17174) even if `tar` in *weren't* provided in Ubuntu by an [essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tar) package maintained by Canonical. See the [help/on-topic], [Are “not only Ubuntu-specific” questions on-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14523), [How do we tell if a question belongs here, or rather at stackoverflow/superuser?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/47), even (as `tar` is much-used in scripts) [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13807).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that is the way the different option styles work and they behave differently.

---

The man page states for *UNIX or short-option style*, the one which is prefixed with a single dash.

> Any number of options not taking arguments can be clustered together after a single dash, e.g. -vkp.   Options that  take  arguments  (whether  mandatory  or  optional), can appear at the end of such a cluster, e.g. -vkpf a.tar.

---

The *traditional style option style*, the one without dashes:

> In traditional style, the first argument is a cluster of option letters and all subsequent arguments supply arguments to those options that require them. The  arguments are read in the same order as the option letters.  Any command line words that remain after all options has been processed are treated as non-optional arguments: file or archive member names.

---

As you can see, the *UNIX or short-option style* expects arguments to options directly after the option.
Whereas the *traditional style option style* expects a block of options and suitable arguments to the options in the right order.

Answer (score 4):

It's clearly described in `man tar`:

> Option styles
>
> ```
>    Options to GNU tar can be given in three different styles.  In
>    traditional style, the first argument is a cluster of option
>    letters and all subsequent arguments supply arguments to those
>    options that require them.  The arguments are read in the same
>    order as the option letters.  Any command line words that
>    remain after all options has been processed are treated as
>    non-optional arguments: file or archive member names.
>
>    For example, the c option requires creating the archive, the v
>    option requests the verbose operation, and the f option takes
>    an argument that sets the name of the archive to operate upon.
>    The following command, written in the traditional style,
>    instructs tar to store all files from the directory /etc into
>    the archive file etc.tar verbosely listing the files being
>    archived:
>
>    tar cfv a.tar /etc
> ```

So in this case:

```
tar cfv collection.tar blues folk jazz
```

`collection.tar` is an argument for `f` and `blues folk jazz` being
the rest of arguments are treated as archive member names.